# How do I implement classes in Processing?

Tags: processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asteroids game in processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944256/asteroids-game-in-processing)

Trying to integrate some classes for Asteroids game into Processing program. How to you implement classes into a processing program? I'm trying to use the classes the professor gave us to use but I'm getting a "The constructor refers to the missing type" error

Comment: Do you have any code or a more specific question? I can't really answer until I have something more concrete to look at.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Shiffman provides a great intro to object-oriented programming in the Processing IDE [here](http://processing.org/learning/objects/).

Each custom Processing class is stored as a .pde file.

If you're trying to include classes encapsulated within .pde files, open the .pde in the folder that contains the setup() and draw() methods.

If you're trying to make a new class, click the arrow button at the upper-right and select New Tab to create a new class.